# AppFabric Installation Error Code 1603

Tags: windows-installer, appfabric

I realize this question has been asked but all solutions posted haven't led to great success as of yet.  Here's 2 of the 3 logs.  I am more than likely missing something here but your assistance is greatly appreciated.

**AppServerSetup**

```
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  ===== Logging started: 2013-05-20 18:14:31+00:00 =====
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  File:             c:\8c8907b82db6eed5f944bf8137\setup.exe
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  InternalName:     Setup.exe
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  OriginalFilename: Setup.exe
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  FileVersion:      1.1.2106.32
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  FileDescription:  Setup.exe
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  Product:          Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server AppFabric
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  ProductVersion:   1.1.2106.32
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  Debug:            False
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  Patched:          False
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  PreRelease:       False
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  PrivateBuild:     False
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  SpecialBuild:     False
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  Language:         Language Neutral
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  OS Name:                   Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  OS Edition:                ServerDatacenter
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  OSVersion:                 Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  CurrentCulture:            en-US
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  Processor Architecture:    AMD64
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  Event Registration Source :    AppFabric_Setup
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : Initiating V1.0 Upgrade module.
2013-05-20 18:14:31, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : V1.0 is not installed.
2013-05-20 18:14:40, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : Initiating V1 Upgrade pre-install.
2013-05-20 18:14:40, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : V1.0 is not installed, not taking backup.
2013-05-20 18:14:40, Information           Setup  Executing C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe with commandline -iru.
2013-05-20 18:14:40, Information           Setup  Return code from aspnet_regiis.exe is 0
2013-05-20 18:14:40, Information           Setup  Windows features successfully enabled.
2013-05-20 18:14:40, Information           Setup  Process.Start: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /quiet /norestart /i "c:\8c8907b82db6eed5f944bf8137\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-64.msi" ADDDEFAULT=Worker,WorkerAdmin,CacheClient,Setup /l*vx "C:\Users\CSAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2013-05-20 18-14-40).log" LOGFILE="C:\Users\CSAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-05-20 18-14-40).log" INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server" LANGID=en-US
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup  Process.ExitCode: 0x00000643
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Error                 Setup  AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Error                 Setup  
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Error                 Setup  AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Error                 Setup  
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Core.SetupException: AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.WindowsInstallerProxy.GenerateAndThrowSetupException(Int32 exitCode, LogEventSource logEventSource)
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.WindowsInstallerProxy.Invoke(LogEventSource logEventSource, InstallMode installMode, String packageIdentity, List`1 updateList, List`1 customArguments)
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.MsiInstaller.InstallSelectedFeatures()
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.MsiInstaller.Install()
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Client.ProgressPage.StartAction()
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup  
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup  === Summary of Actions ===
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup  Required Windows components   :  Completed Successfully
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup  IIS Management Console            :  Completed Successfully
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup  AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server  :  Failed
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup  Hosting Services          :  Failed
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup  Cache Client          :  Failed
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup  Hosting Administration            :  Failed
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup  Microsoft Update  :  Skipped
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup  Microsoft Update          :  Skipped
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup  
2013-05-20 18:15:07, Information           Setup  ===== Logging stopped: 2013-05-20 18:15:07+00:00 =====
```

**AppServerSetupCustomAction**

```
5/20/2013 6:14:47 PM EXEPATH=powershell.exe PARAMS=-command "$content = Get-Content \"c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\\AppFabricServer.xml\"; $content = ForEach-Object -InputObject $content { $_ -replace \"INSTALLPATH\", \"c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\\\" }; Set-Content -value $content -path \"c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\\AppFabricServer.xml\" " LOGFILE=C:\Users\CSAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-05-20 18-14-40).log
ExitCode=0
5/20/2013 6:14:48 PM EXEPATH=powershell.exe PARAMS=-command "$content = Get-Content \"c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\\Consolidator.xml\"; $content = ForEach-Object -InputObject $content { $_ -replace \"INSTALLPATH\", \"c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\\\" }; Set-Content -value $content -path \"c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\\Consolidator.xml\" " LOGFILE=C:\Users\CSAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-05-20 18-14-40).log
ExitCode=0
Executing action : Microsoft.ApplicationServer.InstallHelper.SQMTaskInstallAction
SQMTaskInstall areguments -  /create /tn "\Microsoft\Windows\AppFabric\Customer Experience Improvement Program\Consolidator" /xml "c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\Consolidator.xml"
Output: SUCCESS: The scheduled task "\Microsoft\Windows\AppFabric\Customer Experience Improvement Program\Consolidator" has successfully been created.
5/20/2013 6:14:56 PM EXEPATH=c:\Windows\system32\\sc.exe PARAMS=privs AppFabricEventCollectionService SeChangeNotifyPrivilege/SeCreateGlobalPrivilege/SeImpersonatePrivilege LOGFILE=C:\Users\CSAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-05-20 18-14-40).log
Output: [SC] ChangeServiceConfig2 SUCCESS
ExitCode=0
5/20/2013 6:14:56 PM EXEPATH=c:\Windows\system32\\net.exe PARAMS=localgroup AS_Administrators /comment:"Members of this group can administer AppFabric." /add LOGFILE=C:\Users\CSAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-05-20 18-14-40).log
Output: The command completed successfully.
ExitCode=0
5/20/2013 6:14:56 PM EXEPATH=c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\ase40gc.exe PARAMS=/i ecperfloguser LOGFILE=C:\Users\CSAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-05-20 18-14-40).log
Output: Microsoft (R) AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server Setup Utility. Version 1.1.2106.32
Output: Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Output: Server [Version 6.2.9200] 
Output: OS Edition 0x8: Server Datacenter (full installation)
Output: Load XML resource: (id=101, size=2868)
Output: Load XML resource: (id=101, size=2868)
Output: Load XML resource: (id=102, size=8696)
Output: Load XML resource: (id=102, size=8696)
Output: Load XML resource: (id=103, size=511)
Output: Load XML resource: (id=104, size=546)
Output: Load XML resource: (id=105, size=6759)
Output: Load XML resource: (id=103, size=511)
Output: [ServicingContext]
Output: INSTALLER_WINNING_COMPONENT_IDENTITY=
Output: INSTALLER_WINNING_COMPONENT_PAYLOAD=
Output: INSTALLER_WINNING_COMPONENT_MANIFEST=
Output: INSTALLER_WINNING_COMPONENT_VERSION=
Output: INSTALLER_SHADOWED_COMPONENT_IDENTITY=
Output: INSTALLER_SHADOWED_COMPONENT_PAYLOAD=
Output: INSTALLER_SHADOWED_COMPONENT_MANIFEST=
Output: INSTALLER_SHADOWED_COMPONENT_VERSION=
Output: Servicing type is None.
Output: [RunInstaller]
Output: Attempt 1 of 3: SuppressErrors=False
Output: [Initialize]
Output: Info: Server type is Server
Output: Info: Local group 'Performance Log Users' = 'Performance Log Users'
Output: [Install]
Output: Info: Adding user 'NT SERVICE\AppFabricEventCollectionService' to local group 'Performance Log Users'..
Output: Info: User 'NT SERVICE\AppFabricEventCollectionService' is already a member of group 'Performance Log Users' (ERROR_MEMBER_IN_ALIAS).
Output: Info: Adding user 'NT SERVICE\AppFabricEventCollectionService' to local group 'AS_Administrators'..
Output: Info: Adding user 'NT SERVICE\AppFabricWorkflowManagementService' to local group 'AS_Administrators'..
Output: Info: Added user to local group.
Output: [Commit]
Output: Installer SUCCESS.
Output: Completed install with 0 errors, 0 warnings.
Output: Exit code: 0 The operation completed successfully.
ExitCode=0
5/20/2013 6:14:58 PM EXEPATH=c:\Windows\system32\\net.exe PARAMS=localgroup AS_Observers /comment:"Members of this group can observe AppFabric." /add LOGFILE=C:\Users\CSAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-05-20 18-14-40).log
Error: System error 1379 has occurred.
Error: The specified local group already exists.
ExitCode=2
5/20/2013 6:15:01 PM EXEPATH=c:\Windows\system32\\net.exe PARAMS=localgroup AS_Administrators /delete LOGFILE=C:\Users\CSAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-05-20 18-14-40).log
Output: The command completed successfully.
ExitCode=0
Executing action : Microsoft.ApplicationServer.InstallHelper.SQMTaskUninstallAction
Output: SUCCESS: The scheduled task "\Microsoft\Windows\AppFabric\Customer Experience Improvement Program\Consolidator" was successfully deleted.
```

and then

The meaty one is a bit too big apparently.... though probably contains the problem somewhere hah.

Thanks greatly in advance for the assistance,  I'm really disliking generic error codes right now.

Comment: I think I just found it,  I believe I need to remove my AS_Observers Security Group.  Now to figure out how to do that and see if it works.

Comment: To do that you just go into administrative tools, computer management, local users and groups, and groups and if AS_Observers or AS_Administrators exists, delete it.

as shown here 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637696(v=azure.10).aspx

Hope this helps out anyone who encounters this problem.  This resolved the problem for me and the program is finally installed haha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prior to installing AppFabric, the groups AS_Observers and AS_Administrators must not exist.  To check if they exist for you and to get rid of the that you just go into administrative tools, computer management, local users and groups, and groups and if AS_Observers or AS_Administrators exists, delete it. as shown here [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637696(v=azure.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637696(v=azure.10).aspx) Hope this helps out anyone who encounters this problem. This resolved the problem for me and the program is finally installed haha

Answer (score 0):

few days back i also suffered from the same error. I am sharing few steps that i did n my problem was resolved.

after reading the log file i found this command which i manually executed in command prompt with some modifications and its done!!!

```
Process.Start: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /quiet /norestart /i "c:\338f6462408072c851cf3b1e\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-

64.msi" ADDDEFAULT=Worker,WorkerAdmin,CacheClient,Setup /l*vx "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2013-03-05

18-06-39).log" LOGFILE="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-03-05 18-06-39).log"

INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server" LANGID=en-US
```

Then remove the words Process.Start: and /quiet and execute the command as administrator in MSDOS

```
C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /norestart /i "c:\338f6462408072c851cf3b1e\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-64.msi"

ADDDEFAULT=Worker,WorkerAdmin,CacheClient,Setup /l*vx "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2013-03-05 18-06-

39).log" LOGFILE="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-03-05 18-06-39).log" INSTALLDIR="C:

\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server" LANGID=en-US
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error message from a SharePoint 2013 installation.

I found that there was an illegal char inside my PsModule environment variable and that made my installation fail.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8cf55972-e441-4107-8c0d-1692ad03213d/error-with-installation-of-appfabric-11-on-psmodulepath?forum=velocity

I discover that I couldn't search for the illegal char so I had to look for it manually.

Hope this helps other people out there!