# Why cant i install the appFabric by WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64

Tags: appfabric

this is my detailed installation report error...!
can anyone help me ? i m using window 8 ..do i need make any changes on the PSModulePath ?? or anything else to successful install the appFabric..

```html
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  ===== Logging started: 2015-01-22 17:49:08+08:00 =====
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  File:             c:\794f5ebdea0fa18320da\setup.exe
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  InternalName:     Setup.exe
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  OriginalFilename: Setup.exe
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  FileVersion:      1.1.2106.32
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  FileDescription:  Setup.exe
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  Product:          Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server AppFabric
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  ProductVersion:   1.1.2106.32
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  Debug:            False
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  Patched:          False
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  PreRelease:       False
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  PrivateBuild:     False
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  SpecialBuild:     False
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  Language:         Language Neutral
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  OS Name:                   Windows 8.1 Enterprise N
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  OS Edition:                EnterpriseN
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  OSVersion:                 Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  CurrentCulture:            en-MY
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  Processor Architecture:    AMD64
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  Event Registration Source :    AppFabric_Setup
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : Initiating V1.0 Upgrade module.
2015-01-22 17:49:08, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : V1.0 is not installed.
2015-01-22 17:49:14, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : Initiating V1 Upgrade pre-install.
2015-01-22 17:49:14, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : V1.0 is not installed, not taking backup.
2015-01-22 17:49:14, Information           Setup  Executing C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe with commandline -iru.
2015-01-22 17:49:14, Information           Setup  Return code from aspnet_regiis.exe is 0
2015-01-22 17:49:14, Information           Setup  Windows features successfully enabled.
2015-01-22 17:49:14, Information           Setup  Process.Start: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /quiet /norestart /i "c:\794f5ebdea0fa18320da\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-64.msi" ADDDEFAULT=Worker,WorkerAdmin,CacheClient,Setup /l*vx "C:\Users\red_user2\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2015-01-22 17-49-14).log" LOGFILE="C:\Users\red_user2\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2015-01-22 17-49-14).log" INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server" LANGID=en-US
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup  Process.ExitCode: 0x00000643
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Error                 Setup  AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Error                 Setup  
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Error                 Setup  AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Error                 Setup  
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Core.SetupException: AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.WindowsInstallerProxy.GenerateAndThrowSetupException(Int32 exitCode, LogEventSource logEventSource)
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.WindowsInstallerProxy.Invoke(LogEventSource logEventSource, InstallMode installMode, String packageIdentity, List`1 updateList, List`1 customArguments)
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.MsiInstaller.InstallSelectedFeatures()
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.MsiInstaller.Install()
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Client.ProgressPage.StartAction()
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup  
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup  === Summary of Actions ===
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup  Required Windows components :  Completed Successfully
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup  IIS Management Console   :  Completed Successfully
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup  AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server :  Failed
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup  Hosting Services   :  Failed
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup  Cache Client   :  Failed
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup  Hosting Administration   :  Failed
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup  Microsoft Update :  Skipped
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup  Microsoft Update   :  Skipped
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup  
2015-01-22 17:50:06, Information           Setup  ===== Logging stopped: 2015-01-22 17:50:06+08:00 =====
```

and my PSModulePath is like below

```html
C:\Windows\system32\setx.exe /M PSModulePath \""$str\"";c:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110
```

Comment: This comes down to your environment - something is wrong somewhere. I would suggest doing a Windows Update and a proper reboot then reinstalling AppFabric. Also be sure you are running the installer in Administrator mode (run as administrator). Also, remove the environment variable from the PSModulePath if you can. It can also come down to the fact that it is unable to find the PS path so make sure that the path specified in the environment variable is correct. http://thitos.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/appfabric-installation-failed-because.html

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205927/appfabric-installation-failed-because-installer-msi-returned-with-error-code-1) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655899/appfabric-installation-error-code-1603)

Comment: thx and this is work for me because the PSModulePath is declare is wrong 
and the latest is C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server

and another problem is i doesn't turn on the feature of IIS manager